# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException using cdi

Tags: spring-security, cdi

I am trying to implement authentication and authorization using Spring Security Framework, but I am having a hard time, Im stuck in this exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'clienteBO': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: protected br.com.logtec.dao.GenericCrudDAO br.com.logtec.business.GenericCrudBO.dao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'crudDAO': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: protected javax.persistence.EntityManager br.com.logtec.dao.GenericCrudDAO.entityManager; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManager] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Inject(), @br.com.logtec.factory.DataFactory()}
```

Those are my related classes:

```
@Named("clienteBO")
public class ClienteBO extends PersonificacaoBO<Cliente>{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 119528316663693560L;

public ClienteBO() {
    super();
}

@Override
public Feedback salvar(Cliente instancia) {
    instancia.getPessoa().setCliente(true);
    //TODO PEGAR EMPRESA DO USUARIO LOGADO
//      if(instancia.getEmpresa() == null) 
//          throw new RuntimeException("O cliente deve obrigatoriamente possuir uma empresa");
    return super.salvar(instancia);
}

@Override
public Feedback salvar(Cliente instancia, CrudDAO<Cliente> dao) {
    instancia.getPessoa().setCliente(true);
    return super.salvar(instancia, dao);
}

@Override
protected Exemplo criarExemplo(Cliente pesquisa) throws IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException {
    return super.criarExemplo(pesquisa);
}

@Override
public Feedback salvar(Collection<Cliente> instancias) {
    for (Cliente cliente : instancias) {
        cliente.getPessoa().setCliente(true);
    }
    return super.salvar(instancias);
}

@Override
public Feedback salvar(Collection<Cliente> instancias, CrudDAO<Cliente> dao) {
    for (Cliente cliente : instancias) {
        cliente.getPessoa().setCliente(true);
    }
    return super.salvar(instancias, dao);
}
}

public abstract class PersonificacaoBO<T extends Personificacao> extends GenericCrudBO<T>{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 5475960092794378740L;

@Override
protected Exemplo criarExemplo(T pesquisa) throws IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException {
    Exemplo exemplo = super.criarExemplo(pesquisa);
    exemplo.excludeField("pessoa.cliente");
    exemplo.excludeField("pessoa.funcionario");
    exemplo.excludeField("pessoa.fornecedor");
    exemplo.excludeField("pessoa.usuario");
    exemplo.excludeField("pessoa.contador");
    return exemplo;
}
```

}

```
@Named("crudBO")
public class GenericCrudBO<E extends EntidadeBase> implements CrudBO<E>{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private static final String DEFAULT_ERROR_MESSAGE = "Um erro inesperado ocorreu, contate o administrador do sistema.";
private static final String DEFAULT_SUCESS_MESSAGE = "Operação realizada com sucesso!";

@Inject
@Named("crudDAO")
protected GenericCrudDAO<E> dao;

public GenericCrudBO() {
    super();
}
public GenericCrudBO(GenericCrudDAO<E> dao) {
    super();
    this.dao = dao;
}

public Feedback salvar(E instancia, CrudDAO<E> dao) {
    Feedback feedback;
    try {
        dao.atualizar(instancia);
        feedback = new Feedback(TipoFeedback.SUCESSO, EtapaFeedback.CADASTRO, DEFAULT_SUCESS_MESSAGE);
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        feedback = new Feedback(TipoFeedback.ERRO, EtapaFeedback.CADASTRO, DEFAULT_ERROR_MESSAGE);
        throw e;
    }
    return feedback;
}

public Feedback salvar(Collection<E> instancias, CrudDAO<E> dao) {
    try {
        dao.cadastrar(instancias);
        return new Feedback(TipoFeedback.SUCESSO, EtapaFeedback.CADASTRO, "Operação realizada com sucesso");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return new Feedback(TipoFeedback.ERRO, EtapaFeedback.CADASTRO, "Erro ao salvar, contate o administrador");
    }
}

@Override
public Feedback salvar(Collection<E> instancias) {
    return salvar(instancias, dao);
}

public Feedback salvar(E instancia) {
    return salvar(instancia, dao);
}

@Override
public Feedback deletar(E entidade) {
    Feedback feedback;
    try {
        dao.deletar(entidade);
        feedback = new Feedback(TipoFeedback.SUCESSO, EtapaFeedback.CADASTRO, DEFAULT_SUCESS_MESSAGE);
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        feedback = new Feedback(TipoFeedback.ERRO, EtapaFeedback.DELECAO, DEFAULT_ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
    return feedback;
}

public E pesquisarPorId(Class<E> clazz, Long id) {
    return dao.pesquisarPorId(clazz, id);
}

public E pesquisarPorId(E instancia) {
    return dao.pesquisarPorId(instancia);
}

public List<E> pesquisar(Class<E> clazz) {
    return dao.pesquisarTodos(clazz);
}

/**
 * Pesquisa para entidades simples sem composição
 */
@Override
public List<E> pesquisar(E pesquisa) throws IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException {
    Exemplo exemplo = criarExemplo(pesquisa);
    return dao.pesquisar(exemplo);
}

protected Exemplo criarExemplo(E pesquisa) throws IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException {
    Exemplo exemplo = new Exemplo(pesquisa);
    exemplo.excludeField("serialVersionUID");
    exemplo.setMatchingMode(MatchingMode.ANYWHERE);
    exemplo.excludeZeroes();
    return exemplo;
}

@Override
public int total(E pesquisa) {
    return this.dao.total(pesquisa);
}

public List<E> listarLazy(E pesquisa, int startingAt, int maxPerPage, String sortField, String sortOrder) {
    inicializarCamposPesquisa(pesquisa);
    return this.dao.listarLazy(pesquisa, startingAt, maxPerPage, sortField, sortOrder);
}

protected void inicializarCamposPesquisa(E pesquisa) {
    //método que deverá ser implementado pelas classes filhas que quiserem filtrar os resultados no lazyList
}

public String getListIds(List<EntidadeBase> entidades) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder('(');
    EntidadeBase e = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < entidades.size(); i++) {
        e = entidades.get(i);
        builder.append(e.getId());
        if(i < entidades.size()-1) {
            builder.append(',');
        }
    }
    builder.append(')');
    return builder.toString();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
protected Class<E> getClassType() {
    ParameterizedType parameterizedType = (ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
    return (Class<E>) parameterizedType.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
}
```

}

```
@Named("crudDAO")
public class GenericCrudDAO<E extends EntidadeBase> implements CrudDAO<E>{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(CrudDAO.class);

@Inject 
@DataFactory
protected EntityManager entityManager;

public GenericCrudDAO() {
    super();
}

public GenericCrudDAO(EntityManager entityManager) {
    super();
    this.entityManager = entityManager;
}

@Override
public void cadastrar(E instancia) {
    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
    entityManager.persist(instancia);
    entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
}

public void cadastrar(Collection<E> instancias) {
    try {
        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
        for(E e : instancias) {
            entityManager.merge(e);
        }
        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        entityManager.getTransaction().rollback();
        throw e;
    }
}

@Override
public void atualizar(E instancia) {
    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
    entityManager.merge(instancia);
    entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
}

@Override
public void deletar(E instancia) {
    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
    entityManager.remove(entityManager.merge(instancia));
    entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
}

public E pesquisarPorId(Class<E> clazz, Long id) {
    return (E) entityManager.find(clazz, id);
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public E pesquisarPorId(E instancia) {
    Class<E> clazz = (Class<E>) instancia.getClass();
    return (E) entityManager.find(clazz, instancia.getId());
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<E> pesquisarTodos(Class<E> clazz) {
    List<E> lista = new ArrayList<E>();
    lista = entityManager.createQuery(" FROM " + clazz.getName()).getResultList();
    return lista;
}

@Override
public List<E> pesquisar(Exemplo exemplo) throws IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException {
    return QBE.using(entityManager).getList(exemplo);
}

@Override
public E pesquisarUnico(Exemplo exemplo) throws IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException {
    return QBE.using(entityManager).getSingle(exemplo);
}

@Override
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<E> pesquisar(String queryString) {
    return entityManager.createQuery(queryString).getResultList();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public List<E> pesquisar(String queryString, Map<String, Object> param) {
    String key = null;
    Query query = entityManager.createQuery(queryString);
    for(Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : param.entrySet()) {
        key = entry.getKey().trim();
        key = key.startsWith(":") ? key.substring(1) : key;
        query.setParameter(key, entry.getValue());
    }
    return query.getResultList();
}

public int total(E pesquisa) {
    Long count = 0L;

    try {;
        Query q = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT count(*) FROM "
                + pesquisa.getClass().getName());
        count = (Long) q.getSingleResult();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("Erro ao buscar total listagem lazy", e);
    }
    return count.intValue();
}

public void rollback() {
    entityManager.getTransaction().rollback();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
protected Class<E> getClassType() {
    ParameterizedType parameterizedType = (ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
    return (Class<E>) parameterizedType.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<E> listarLazy(E pesquisa, int startingAt, int maxPerPage,
        String sortField, String sortOrder) {
    List<E> lista = new ArrayList<E>();
    try {
        Query q = entityManager.createQuery("FROM "
                + pesquisa.getClass().getName());
        q.setFirstResult(startingAt);
        q.setMaxResults(maxPerPage);
        lista = q.getResultList();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("Erro ao buscar listagem Lazy", e);
    }
    return lista;
}
```

}

I'm a begginer on Spring Security, being so, any help is welcome, thanks

Comment: If your question is about Spring, then it's probably not about CDI.

Comment: I am using only Spring Security, being so I just removed the Spring tag, thanks for your attention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get this right, you want to use Spring Security for security and CDI for dependency injection.

In that case, you need to make sure that Spring and CDI don't try to manage the same beans. Even when you don't use Spring Core directly, you now have both Spring and CDI on your classpath. When Spring discovers  `javax.inject.Inject` on its classpath, it will treat `@Inject` as synonymous to `@Autowired` and try to inject Spring beans into the annotated injection target.

That's why you get the exception - it's Spring and not CDI complaining about a missing bean.